# Android Rajawali Texture View Fragment OnResume(), OnPause()

Tags: android, android-fragments, opengl-es, 3d, rajawali

I have an android application which should work as a car monitor; I get different signal into android thanks to a CAN bus system installed on the car.

My company asked me to develope an application which can interact and monitor all the inputs and outputs.

I've got an Activity which handle different fragments.

In the main fragment, which is the HomeFragment, i've to show an interactive 3D model of the car.

While looking on the internet for a way of displaying 3D models i found this library called [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali).

This "Engine" provide Texture and Surface View. I decided to use the Texture view.

I extended the Rajawaly render class, i added a RajawalyTexture view to my xml, i was able to display obj files inside it, and i was able to translate them and the camera too.

After a couple of Test Projects for understanding how it works i decided to implement it inside the HomeFragment of the Car monitor which i was developing.

Everything looks good and works fine till i move replace the Home fragment with other fragments, when i return in the Homefragment i get an error which tell me

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.rajawali3d.view.TextureView$GLThread.onResume()' on a null object reference`

So my question is, how should i manage the Rajawaly TextureView inside a fragment in my Activity?

I found the documentation really cofusing, and i didn't understand which version of the software is the wiki on GitHub referring to. Is there someone managed to get concrete results from this lib? Does someone know other ways of displaying 3D models inside an android app?

I'm getting crazy, thanks for the help, Here's some code:

**The OnResume method of the HomeFragment:**

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume of FragmentHome");
    use_HandlerBinding(); //An Handler
    BTNLuci.setEnabled(true); //Some Buttons
    BTNClima.setEnabled(true); //Some Buttons
    BTNServizi.setEnabled(true); //Some Buttons
    if(rajawaliTextureView==null && renderer==null)
    {
        ProgressBar PB = (ProgressBar)getView().findViewById(R.id.PBrajawaly);  //a progress bar 
        rajawaliTextureView = (TextureView) getView().findViewById(R.id.RajawalyTextureView);
        renderer = new Renderer(getContext(),rajawaliTextureView,PB);
        rajawaliTextureView.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
        rajawaliTextureView.setOnTouchListener(renderer);
    }
    rajawaliTextureView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

**The OnPause:**

```
  @Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "OnPause of FragmentHome");
    rajawaliTextureView.onPause();
    HandlerBinding.removeCallbacks(RunableHandlerBinding);  //Some Handler
    super.onPause();
}
```

rajawaliSurfaceView and renderer are two static istance declared in the fragment and initialized inside the onCreateViewof the Fragment.

If You need more code, ask, thank you again.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to use SetPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true) to preserve the Texture view to remove his content when the fragment goes onPause().

It wasn't able to make it works, probably because of the fragment lifecycle, so i'm posting my code here again

**Activity**

This is the portion of code which I call to add replace a fragment in my Activity:

```
 public void changeFragment(Fragment frag, boolean saveInBackstack, boolean animate) {
    String backStateName = ((Object) frag).getClass().getName();
    String TAG ="Fragment manager";

    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            if (animate) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: animate");
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_from_right, R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_from_left);
            }

            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, frag, backStateName);

            if (saveInBackstack) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: addToBackTack " + backStateName);
                transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: NO addToBackTack");
            }

            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            // custom effect if fragment is already instanciated
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to commit fragment, could be activity as been killed in background. " + exception.toString());
    }
}
```

**FragmentHome**

This is the first Fragment which gets showed, it contains the 3D model, the Rajawaly Texture View and the Renderer:

```
TextureView RajawaliTextureView;
Renderer render;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onCreate of FragmentHome");
    int result;
    ActivityManager activityManager =
            (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ConfigurationInfo configInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    if (configInfo.reqGlEsVersion != ConfigurationInfo.GL_ES_VERSION_UNDEFINED) {
        result= configInfo.reqGlEsVersion;
    } else {
        result= 1 << 16; // Lack of property means OpenGL ES version 1
    }
    Log.e("reqGlEsVersion", String.valueOf(result));
    Log.e("getGlEsVersion", configInfo.getGlEsVersion());

        SetUpRenderRajawali();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onCreateView of FragmentHome");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();

    (...)


    RajawaliTextureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.RajaView);
    RajawaliTextureView.setSurfaceRenderer(render);
    RajawaliTextureView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume of FragmentHome");

    (...)

    if(render!=null && RajawaliTextureView!=null) {
        RajawaliTextureView.onResume();
        render.onResume();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "OnPause of FragmentHome");

    (...)

    if(render!=null && RajawaliTextureView!=null) {
        RajawaliTextureView.onPause();
        render.onPause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}


private PointLight LuceGlobale;
private static Object3D ModelloAmbulanza;
private Object3D Container;
private Material MaterialeGenerico;

 //RAJAWALI RENDERER
private void SetUpRenderRajawali()
{
    render = new Renderer(getActivity()) {

        @Override
        protected void initScene() {
            Container = new Object3D();
            MaterialeGenerico = new Material();
            MaterialeGenerico.enableLighting(true);
            MaterialeGenerico.setDiffuseMethod(new DiffuseMethod.Lambert());

            LuceGlobale = new PointLight();
            LuceGlobale.setPosition(20, 40, 0);
            LuceGlobale.setPower(15);
            final LoaderOBJ loaderOBJ = new   LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, R.raw.xlink_obj);
            loadModel(loaderOBJ, call, R.raw.xlink_obj);
        }



        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRender(final long elapsedTime, final double deltaTime) {
            super.onRender(elapsedTime, deltaTime);
            try {
                ModelloAmbulanza.rotate(Vector3.Axis.Y, 1.0);                
            }catch (Exception e)
            {}

        }


        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenderSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig config, GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            super.onRenderSurfaceCreated(config, gl, width, height);

        }

        @Override
        public void onRenderSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            super.onRenderSurfaceDestroyed(surface);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onModelLoadComplete(ALoader aLoader) {
    RajLog.d("Model load complete: " + aLoader);
    final LoaderOBJ obj = (LoaderOBJ) aLoader;
    ModelloAmbulanza = obj.getParsedObject();
    ModelloAmbulanza.setPosition(0,0,0);
    render.getCurrentScene().addChild(ModelloAmbulanza);
    render.getCurrentCamera().setPosition(0,3,20);
    render.getCurrentScene().setBackgroundColor((float)0.14, (float) 0.14,(float)0.14,0);
}

@Override
public void onModelLoadFailed(ALoader aLoader) {
    RajLog.e("Model load failed: " + aLoader);
}
```

Comment: When you "return to the home fragment" (so supposing it was shown at least one time before), does "onResume of FragmentHome" shows up in the log ? And in this situation is rajawaliTextureView null or renderer null ? Also have you tried recreating rajawaliTextureView each time onResume is called (might not be a good solution but worth a test...) ?

Comment: recreating rajawaliTextureView actually works, but the Objs a want to show are quite big, and the parser takes a lot of time.
Fourther more the memory usage increase every time i pause and resume the fragment

Comment: Depending on how rajawaliTextureView is made, it may "lose" its OpenGLES context on pause, so the OpenGLES context needs to be recreated on resume and then all data has to be re-uploaded to the GPU, I cannot tell you much more sorry...

Comment: I quickly checked the github, please try to call `rajawaliTextureView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true)` when creating the rajawaliTextureView, the default value is false, so yes the GLES context is destroyed when onPause is called.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this, anyway i'm currently trying to "save" the TextureView content before the OnPause and to reload it inside the TextureView in onRenderSurfaceCreated() and it seems to work.

Comment: Ok, happy to know I helped ! Note that setPreserveEGLContextOnPause (or similar solutions) is used a lot for example in Android games to preserve the context when user minimizes the game (and when the game resumes, usually it does not need to reload any 3D data). So I would tend to say that allowing the context to be destroyed and trying to "restore" data on resume is the "old way" to handle this kind of issue (a long time ago you had no other choice than letting the context be destroyed and recreating all GPU textures, buffers etc. on resume)

Comment: Currently i tryed in the "Old Way". When the fragment goes onPause() i don't destroy the renderer and in case it goes onResume() i attach it to the texture view again. Inside the renderer the onRenderSurfaceCreated() get called and i can load the old scene again, and then insert the previous models which were already been parsed the first time.  Sometimes everything seems working fine but the texture view doesn't show anything until i restart the application, and if i set a breakpoint nothing get parsed and loaded. I'm going to try your "New Way" now. I'll post the results. thanks! :)